# What does 2>&1 Mean in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following script:

```
if( $timeout -ne $null )
{
    & $var$timeout 2>&1 > $logDir\$logName
}
else
{
    & $var2>&1 >  $logDir\$logName
}
```

I'm curious about what `2>&1` is; or, what it represents. I don't know what it's called, otherwise, I'd look it up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In the shell, what is " 2>&1 "?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-is-21)

Comment: `2>&1` looks like IO-redirection to me... but I'm not all that familiar with powershell.

Comment: @x0n does answer that apply to Windows? It looks like Unix to me; is there any difference?

Comment: in your powershell console type Get-Help about_Redirection

Comment: @Blaine Yes, that applies to Windows, which took the syntax directly from Unix shells.

Comment: The document for 2>&1 is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.4

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It redirects standard error (the 2) to the same place as standard output (the 1)

Answer (score 33):

The docs are your friends.  From `PS> man about_Redirection`

```
The Windows PowerShell redirection operators are as follows.

Operator  Description                Example
--------  ----------------------     ------------------------------
<snip>

2>&1      Sends errors (2) and       Get-Process none, Powershell 2>&1
          success output (1)
          to the success
          output stream.

<snip>

The syntax of the redirection operators is as follows:

   <input> <operator> [<path>\]<file>

If the specified file already exists, the redirection operators that do not
append data (> and n>) overwrite the current contents of the file without
warning. However, if the file is a read-only, hidden, or system file, the
redirection fails. The append redirection operators (>> and n>>) do not
write to a read-only file, but they append content to a system or hidden
file.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as I said in my post, how can I search for something if I don't know what it is. If I knew it was redirection, I'd be able to use your answer, and wouldn't have needed to post.

Comment: You can search the help system with wildcards.  `Get-Help '*&1*'` points to the above topic.